# Число у слова "СанПиН"

Tags: орфография

Какое число у слова "СанПиН"?

Comment: Liana, вопрос должен содержать ВОПРОС, а не пустое поле!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строго говоря, СанПиН - несклонямая аббревиатура,а грамматические признаки таких аббревиатур определяют по признакам ведущего слова. СанПиН - сан. нормы и правила - множ.ч., значит, и аббревиатура множ. числа.В документах так их и используют, но всё чаще уважаемые, крупные СМИ стали использовать склоняемую форму: (http://oprf.ru/press/news/2011/newsitem/9196 ) С 1 сентября вступают в силу новые санитарные нормы и правила (СанПИНы), резко ужесточающие требования к оснащению школ и образовательному процессу.В новых СанПИНах прописаны и жесткие требования к спортплощадкам.(написание в соответствии с транслитерацией).

Однако  иногда  склоняют и по типу м. р., ед. ч. - в СанПиНе. Это объясняется разговорным использованием транслитерации: СанПиН-    SanPin  (Sanitary Rules and Standards).Транслитерация в русском языке воспринимается на слух - как звуковые аббревиатуры, т. е. с конечным согласным, что позволяет относить слово к м.р. ед.ч. Но тогда слово пишется  СанПИН, союз не выделяется, а значит, расшифровка нарушается,  это не норма, но частотность такого словоупотребления действительно может сделать его нормой.

Answer (score 4):

Словарями не фиксируется. Нынешнее употребление во множественном числе можно признать приемлемым, но если слово сохранится в языке, то можно ожидать приобретение им мужского рода и единственного числа.

Answer (score 1):

Санитарные правила и нормы. Множественное число.
Пишут "настоящие санпин..."

Comment: Пишут и "СаНПиНы". Не аргумент.